# concatenating a field in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new and don't have much experience in database. I've a front end GUI flex application and saves user interactions to MySQL database.

Database will have fields like this.

ID  Name  ChartName SequenceOfActions rest--of--fields

I want to update the database whenever the user makes GUI change or interacts. I know the update command but it will delete older value and update.

I want something like append command which will save the values in the database.

Comment: You want to keep multiple versions of each record? Or multiple copies of each field's values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `CONCAT`? Something like:

`UPDATE my_table SET my_field = CONCAT(my_field, 'New content');`

Comment: oh this is great! does this work for fields realted to VARCHAR only or even text, int?

Comment: As long as the resulting content fits the field type it should work. Read up on it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat